# how to bond coordinate points after changing values by using a loop in matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, graph, line

ı need to change  coordinate values and ı need to bond them

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([
    [0, 2],
    [0, 3],
    [0, 6],
    [0, 7],
    [7, 9],
    [7, 8],
])
list =data.tolist()
x, y = data.T
for x,y in list:
    x+=1 
    plt.scatter(x,y,color='red',)
```

ı used a loop to change the values, everything worked properly so far.

```
plt.plot(x,y,)
```

ı dont know why but it does not work properly, ı couldnt bond the coordinate values after changed it by using a loop (it works without using a loop)

```
plt.show(x,y)
```

this is the graph without using:

```
for x,y in list:
        x+=1 
        plt.scatter(x,y,color='red')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUQro.png

ı try to make this graph with the new coordinate values

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "bonding the scatter"

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do `plt.scatter(x, y, c='red', marker = 'o')`? This is the proper way for a scatter plot.

Comment: I meant the bonding coordinate values with a line actually, so, ı used “plt.plot(x,y) “

Comment: ı edited the question, ı hope it is more understandable..By the way ı need to make changeable graph for specific coordinate so ı used a loop or maybe" if" steatment  but both of them does not work properly. Im not good  enough so I dont know if there is a easier way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib and Numpy are designed to go hand in hand and arithmetic on arrays is MUCH simpler than on lists, so forget about converting to lists

```
data = np.array([ # shape of data is (6, 2) - six rows, two columns
    [0, 2],
    [0, 3],
    [0, 6],
    [0, 7],
    [7, 9],
    [7, 8],
]) 

x, y = data.T # x, y are two Numpy arrays, their shape (6,) because data.T is (2, 6)

# create a figure with two sublots in a single row, "1,2"
# stretch the h-size to accomodate two subplots,
# use exactly the same x limits and ticks on both subplots
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,3), sharex=True)

# in one subplot the original data, in the other the modified x
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax1.plot(x+1, y)  # simply add 1 to the array x
```

Comment: Thats okay, but what if ı need to change only the some arrays instead of the all of the  values? In list, ı can choose the specific one and ı can only change that's x or y value.

Comment: … This is another question.